# First post in Wordpress blog displays incorrectly

Tags: wordpress

I am styling a wordpress theme and the top blog post always displays incorrectly. The code is here:

```
    <div class="bordered centered">
    <p class="negative-margin alignleft header"><?php the_title(); ?></p><p class="negative-margin alignright date"><?php the_date(); ?></p><div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
    <div id="entry-left"><?php   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
    echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); 
    echo '</a>';?>
</div>
<div class="entry-right">
    <?php the_content( __( 'More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'huckleberry' ) ); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'huckleberry' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="entry-right">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="header">Details</p><br />
                <?php $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link', false ); ?>
                <?php if ($my_meta): var_dump($my_meta) ?>
                <?php foreach ($my_meta as $currMeta): ?>
                <?php if( $currMeta && '' != $currMeta ): $currMeta=explode($currMeta,";",2);?>
                     <a href="<?php echo $my_meta[1] ?>"><?php $my_meta[0];?></a>
                <?php endif; endforeach; endif; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');?>">
                <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image');?>">
                    <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'tertiary-image'); endif; ?>
                 </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <a href="<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image');?>">
                 <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'fourth-image'); endif; ?>
                </a>
            <td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

with the relevant CSS here:

```
.alignleft {
float:left;
}
.alignright {
float:right;
}
.bordered {
border:2px solid black;
}
.negative-margin {
margin-top:-25px;
margin-left:5px;
background:white;
}
.header {
font-size:200%;
}
.date {
font-size:150%;
}
.centered {
width:640px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#entry-left {
float:left;
width:200px;
}
.entry-right {
    float:right;
width:430px;
}
```

All the other posts have the border, with the title and date on the border, but the top post has a border that goes over the header, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywIhy.jpg

I'm relatively new to Wordpress and can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

Also, I'm trying to use Custom Fields to display links under "details." The idea is to have the key for the links always be "link", and the value to be in the format "description;url" so that I can break the value into two values to have a link description and URL display. I'm unable to get that to actually display any links. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps irrelevant, but where do you close the following divs? `<div class="bordered centered">` and `<div id="entry-left">`?

This is not exactly answering your second questions, but as for custom fields: I would suggest using a great WP module - ACF. It allows you to create and read values of custom-created fields easily, coming with many more useful features. The plugin can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: I didn't copy all the way down to where they were closed, I apologize. I double checked my divs and they are closed correctly, but the problem persists.

Comment: I believe #entry-left should be closed somewhere within `<div class="entry-content">` Isn't it correct? Not seeing the whole code, the indentation tells me it would be the problem.

Comment: I fixed the <div> closings, but I'm still having the same issue. (I went through and cleaned up the indenting to make where the divs open and close more obvious)

Comment: Could you paste your outputted HTML (the one that causes trouble) and CSS code into jsfiddle? That would help a lot

Comment: Check my version of your code. I added only a `clear:both` div after your top navigation divs. http://jsfiddle.net/JFmMm/